# WPF - Get text from static Dictionary Singleton

Tags: c#, wpf, static, localization, indexer

I got the localization for my project in an external class library, because I want only one `Lang.csv` file for my translations.

For this I got a static instance `Translator.TI` with an indexer in the namespace `TimeTracking.Lang` and my WPF Application is in the namespace `TimeTracking.View` in the main project (so different projects, but same basic namespace).

```
namespace TimeTracking.Lang
{
    public class Translator
    {
        public static readonly Translator TI = new Translator();
        private readonly Dictionary<string, Translation> _translations;

        public string this[string key]
        {
            get { ... }
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Now I want to load my translations from this static singleton instance into the view.

```
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:TimeTracking.Lang;assembly=TimeTrackingShared"
    Title="{x:Static p.Translator.TI[TimeTracking]}"
>
    ...
</Window>
```

**Question:** Is this possible and how? And if not: Could I do this by using a class property targeting the static singleton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use indexer with `{x:Static}` extension. You could achieve this with `Binding`, for example:

```
Title="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Translator.TI}, Path='[TimeTracking]'}"
```

It is also a good idea to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `Translator` class to avoid binding memory leaks and to enable property change notifications.